# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 in java with mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have got a problem in inserting value in *rewards* table. Try to solve it and found other post as well but I could not find any solution.

```
    String sql1 = "INSERT INTO rewards(project_id, 1st_reward,1st_description,                 2nd_reward, 2nd_description, 3rd_reward, 3rd_description, 4th_reward, 4th_description, 5th_reward, 5th_description)  "
                                        + "values('"
                                        + projectId
                                        + "','"
                                        + rwd1.getText().toString()
                                        + "','"
                                        + rwd1Desc.getText().toString()
                                        + "','"
                                        + rwd1.getText().toString()
                                        + "','"
                                        + rwd2.getText().toString()
                                        + "','"
                                        + rwd2Desc.getText().toString()
                                        + "','"
                                        + rwd3.getText().toString()
                                        + "','"
                                        + rwd3Desc.getText().toString()
                                        + "','"
                                        + rwd4.getText().toString()
                                        + "','"
                                        + rwd4Desc.getText().toString()
                                        + "','"
                                        + rwd5.getText().toString()
                                        + "','"
                                        + rwd5Desc.getText().toString()
                                        + "')"; 
stmt.executeUpdate(sql1);
```

Comment: This is how we don't assemble queries.

Comment: This kinds of assembling queries, isn't best practice ??

Comment: Yes, instead of concatenating strings, you should use prepared statements. That is a lot more safe, friendly, and generally nicer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 11 columns, and 12 values...

you have one extra

```
+ "','"
+ rwd1.getText().toString()
+ "','"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned 11 columns in your SQL statement but setting 12 values for it. This is causing

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 in java with mysql
>   database

Update your query to use the right number of columns and then use the same number and type of values.

Answer (score 0):

The duplicate column others are mentioning in your values is one of the `rwd1.getText().toString()` calls:

```
...
+ rwd1.getText().toString()
+ "','"
+ rwd1Desc.getText().toString()
+ "','"
+ rwd1.getText().toString()
...
```

---

Another way to more cleanly assemble your query would be:

```
EntityManager em;

Query query = em.createQuery("INSERT INTO rewards(project_id,1st_reward,1st_description,2nd_reward,2nd_description,3rd_reward,3rd_description,4th_reward,4th_description,5th_reward,5th_description) values (:projectId,:rwd1,:rwd1Desc,:rwd2,:rwd2Desc,:rwd3,:rwd3Desc,:rwd4,:rwd4Desc,:rwd5,:rwd5Desc)");

query.setParameter("projectId", projectId);
query.setParameter("rwd1", rwd1.getText().toString());
query.setParameter("rwd1Desc", rwd1Desc.getText().toString());
query.setParameter("rwd2", rwd2.getText().toString());
query.setParameter("rwd2Desc", rwd2Desc.getText().toString());
query.setParameter("rwd3", rwd3.getText().toString());
query.setParameter("rwd3Desc", rwd3Desc.getText().toString());
query.setParameter("rwd4", rwd4.getText().toString());
query.setParameter("rwd4Desc", rwd4Desc.getText().toString());
query.setParameter("rwd5", rwd5.getText().toString());
query.setParameter("rwd5Desc", rwd5Desc.getText().toString());

query.executeUpdate();
```

---

Here are some more resources for this method: [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-query-examples-hql/), [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/JPQL01/entry/more_good_examples_on_easily), and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbrg.html).